# Why should someone tag in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I've met a lot of developers that swear by tagging gits. Personally, I have never seen the use in it.

I understand that you can put version information in a tag, but why not just put that information in the commit message?

**I'm just confused about what value the tag adds that the commit message cannot.**

Comment: A tag is essentially a branch that is designed not to change. You use them for the same reason you use branches (having names for particular points in history, rather than just hashes), but you use branches for when you expect that name to change location, and tags when you don't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tags allow you to reference a specific commit in the repository. Using for instance a *version* tag, you can easily get the commit in your project that corresponds to e.g. *version 1.5*. This is preferable to remembering the hash of a specific commit, or scrolling/greping through log information to find out which commit represents version 1.5.

This could be useful for many reasons, but consider just one: you have two clients running different versions of your software, *client A* at version `1.5` and *client B* using version `2.0`. Client A reports a bug, and you can't just upgrade their install and instead need to address the bug in the version `1.5` code. Tagging version `1.5` allows you to easily get back to the code that they're running and work on a bugfix.

Answer (score 8):

In Git, a *tag* lets you assign a symbolic name (something that is easy to remember) to a specific commit. This allows you to refer to that commit by *name*, instead of by raw *commit id*.

I sometimes add a local tag when I'm repeatedly referring back to a specific version, such as a point just before a lot of work was done. I also use annotated tags to tag a specific release version number (annotated tags can easily be pushed and can contain additional description other than just a name).

Answer (score 5):

The commit message is usually used to give more information about why the commit was made than just 'it is version X'.

Using the tag, you can get back to the tagged version without having to scroll through the log to find the right commit number; you check out the tagged version directly.  And the more limited name space for tags is a benefit here, not a hindrance.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can [**sign** a tag](http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html#signed_tags), which is important when you want to **push** (ie publish to another repo)

See "[Why do some open source projects do not accept pull requests, but emailing patch files only](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149199/why-do-some-open-source-projects-do-not-accept-pull-requests-but-emailing-patch/149202#149202)".

So why you would tag in Git (a *distributed* version control system)?

You can tag for referring to a tree with a symbolic name (as explained in the other answers).

But you can also sign your tag in order to contribute to another repo by vouching for the integrity of the content.
The recipient only needs to do is [check that tag signature](http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html#verifying_tags) in order to confirm it comes from a trusted source.